# how to prevent set default value if property has already value in edit view and model in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on edit view, i want set the default value for **Create_Time** and **Last_Update**

here is model

```
public class TVSerialEpisode
{
    private DateTime _CurrentTime = DateTime.Now;
    [Key]
    public Int64 Video_ID { get; set; }
    public string Episode_Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool Is_Active { get; set; }
    public DateTime Create_Time
    {
        get { return _CurrentTime; }
        set { _CurrentTime = value; }
    }
    public DateTime Last_Update
    {
        get { return _CurrentTime; }
        set { _CurrentTime = value; }
    }
}
```

here is controller

```
 public ActionResult EditEpisode(TVSerialEpisode tvepisode)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            tvContext.Entry(tvepisode).State = EntityState.Modified;                
            tvContext.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("ListAllEpisode"});
        }
        return View(tvepisode);
    }
```

i am not sending **Create_Time** and **Last_Update** value from view. And it is working fine with create view. But the problem is that when i am trying to edit view and save it then it also set the default value for **Create_Time** and **Last_Update**  , but i want only **Last_Update** should be update, not **Create_Time**

Comment: Did you try storing the Create_Time in a hidden field and let it come back along with POST data? Otherwise you need to query first, get the original Create_Time for that record and overwrite inside controller before saving the context.

Comment: @Nick Carter - If I understand it correctly, for the update view you do not want the Create_Time value set to the default value?  If not the default value then what value do you want it to be set to?

Comment: @siva_gopal : yes i already try the hidden field for **Create_Time** but same result , every time i update the records it change the value for **Create_Time** too, i think i should not provide the default value for **Create_Time** inside model

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TVSerialEpisode
{
    private DateTime _CurrentTime = DateTime.Now;
    private DateTime _lastUpdate = DateTime.Now;
    [Key]
    public Int64 Video_ID { get; set; }
    public string Episode_Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool Is_Active { get; set; }
    public DateTime Create_Time
    {
        get { return _CurrentTime; }
        set { _CurrentTime = value; }
    }
    public DateTime Last_Update
    {
        get { return _lastUpdate; }
        set { _lastUpdate = value; }
    }
}
```

Here i created another datetime object for **Last_Update** and set hidden field inside edit view and now it works fine, the issue was that when model class called inside controller it set the default value for datetime object _CurrentTime and both Create_Time and Last_Update were using the same object value, now i seperated them.